# Grub Boot loader will not install to Raid Drive

Tags: grub2

I am trying to Install Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS onto a Fujitsu Primergy Server and Cannot get the Grub Boot loader to install. I have initialized the drive many times and this is a completely clean install. Is there a different way to force Grub to Install?

Answer (score 0):

We must make sure that the GRUB2 bootloader is installed on both hard drives, /dev/sda and /dev/sdb:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install /dev/sdb
update-grub
update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: I cannot get to a command line to enter these commands, I am using the Ubuntu installer booting from a DVD, the grub installer fails every time, and the server will not boot into Ubuntu without a bootloader.

Comment: You should use a live-dvd to install the Grub